# JSR223 Assertion в JMeter

Tags: javascript, json, jmeter, groovy

Есть два апи: одно - дает рандомного пользователя с информацией о нем, второе - предоставляет информацию о вероятной национальности человека по его имени.
В Jmeter настроил запрос по первому апи с JSON экстракторами: на получение имени и на получение национальности из первого запроса.
Вторым запросом получаю список национальностей по имени. Теперь мне нужно проверить совпадает ли национальность из первого запроса с какой-либо из второго запроса (их несколько).
Если национальность совпадает, то сохранить некоторую информацию в CSV файл.
Может ли кто-нибудь подсказать groovy скрипт для парсинга национальностей из второго запроса, проверки совпадения национальности по спарсенному списку и если есть матч, то сохранить инфу? Названия переменных в скрипте можно писать любые, я сам поменяю.

UPD: написал такой скрипт:

```
def data = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData());
def natList = object.country.each{entry -> entry};
def countryList = natList.country_id;

if('${nationality}' in countryList {
new File("C:/JMETER/photo/${lastname}.jpg") << new URL ("${largePic}")
new File("C:/JMETER/${lastname}.csv").withWriter { fileWriter ->
    def csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, CSVFormat.DEFAULT)
    csvFilePrinter.printRecord(['${username}','${lastname}','${nationality}',"C:/JMETER/photo/${lastname}.jpg"]) } }
```

загнал его в ассертшн, но тест проходит с ошибкой. Что не так с кодом?

Answer (score 0):

С кодом "не так" примерно это:

1. `object` нигде не объявлен, соответственно линия `def natList = object.country.each{entry -> entry};` и все что после нее работать не будут, а "ошибка" будет примерно такая:

   > No such property: object for class: Script1
2. Если `CSVPrinter` это вот этот [CSVPrinter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVPrinter.html) - библиотеку, которая его реализует нужно добавить в [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) а в "ваш" "код" - [import](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports)
3. Использование переменных `${таким вот образом}` [так себе идея](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) потому что первое значение будет скомпилировано и закешировано и если переменная будет меняться в следуюших итерациях скрипт все равно будет использовать начальное значение. Лучше делать что-то вроде `vars.get('nationality')`

Еще полезные советы: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)